# Split large string into smaller chunks in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a large string separated by newline character. This string contains 100 lines. I want to split these line into small chunks say chunk of 20 also based on newline character.

Let's say the string variable is like this,

> Line1 
> This is line2 
> Line3 is here 
> I am Line4

Now I want to split this large string variable into small chunks of 2. The result should be 2 strings as,

> Line1
>  This is line2
>
> ---
>
> Line3 is here 
> I am Line4

Using Split function, I am not getting the expected results. Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

Comment: Splitting on newline will give you 4 strings, not two...why would you expect anything different?

Comment: split will give u 4 lines. y dont you merge the two strings n get it in a new array.

Comment: Use Split and String bulider class .Think once this will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple approach (Split on Environment.NewLine, then loop and append):

```
public static List<string> GetStringSegments(string originalString, int linesPerSegment)
{

    List<string> segments = new List<string>();
    string[] allLines = originalString.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int linesProcessed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(allLines[i]);
        linesProcessed++;

        if (linesProcessed == linesPerSegment
            || i == allLines.Length-1)
        {
            segments.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
            inesProcessed = 0;
        }
    }

    return segments;
}
```

The above approach is slightly inefficient since it requires splitting the string first into individual lines, which creates unnecessary strings. A string of 1000 lines will create an array of 1000 strings.  We can improved this if we just scan the string and search for `\n`:

```
public static List<string> GetStringSegments(string original, int linesPerSegment)
{
    List<string> segments = new List<string>();

    int startIndex = 0;
    int newLinesEncountered = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    {
        if (original[i] == '\n')
        {
            newLinesEncountered++;
        }

        if (newLinesEncountered == linesPerSegment
            || i == original.Length - 1)
        {
            segments.Add(original.Substring(startIndex, (i - startIndex + 1)));
            startIndex = i + 1;
            newLinesEncountered = 0;
        }
    }

    return segments;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the batch operator from http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/08/batch-or-partition-a-collection-with-linq

```
string s = "[YOUR DATA]";
var lines = s.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var batch in lines.Batch(20))
{
  foreach(batchLine in batch)
  {
    Console.Writeline(batchLine);
  }
}

static class LinqEx
{
  // from http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/08/batch-or-partition-a-collection-with-linq
  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                int batchSize)
  {
    List<T> nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
      nextbatch.Add(item);
      if (nextbatch.Count == batchSize)
      {
        yield return nextbatch;
        nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
      }
    }
    if (nextbatch.Count > 0)
      yield return nextbatch;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As several people mentioned, using `string.Split` will split the whole string into memory, which might be an allocation-heavy operation. This is why we have the `TextReader` class and its descendants, which *should* provide better memory performance, and might also be clearer, logically:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(myString))
{
    do
    {
        StringBuilder newString = null;
        StringWriter newStringWriter = null;
        if (lineCounter % 20 == 0)
        {
             newString = new StringBuilder();
             newStringWriter = new StringWriter(newString);
             newStringCollection.Add(newString);
        } 
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
             newStringWriter.WriteLine(line);
             lineCounter++;
        }
    }
    while (line != null)
}
```

We're using the `StringReader` to read our big string, one line at a time. And the corresponding `StringWriter` writes those lines to the new string, one line a time. After every 20 lines, we start a new `StringBuilder` (and the appropriate `StringWriter` wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

split the strings by newline.
Then merge/fetch the number of strings together while using the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "Line1\nThis is line2 \nLine3 is here\nI am Line4";

string [] str = s.split('\n');

List<String> str1 = new List<String>();

for(int i=0; i<str.Length; i+=2)
{
    string ss = str[i];

    if(i+1 <str.Length)
        ss += '\n' + str[i+1];

    str1.Add(ss);
}

str = str1.ToArray();
```

If condition has been checked inside loop because may be the length of str is odd

Answer (score 0):

```
var strAray = myLongString.Split('\n').ToList();
var skip=0;
var take=20;

var chunk = strAray.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();

While(chunk.Count >0)
{
foreach(var line in chunk)
{
// use line string
}
skip++;
chunk = strAray.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList()
}
```